# Counting matches between 2 lists (taking order into account)

Tags: python

I'm rather new to programming, but what I want to do is basically this:
If I have 2 lists:

```
ls1 = ("red", "red",  "red",  "black", "black", "black")
ls2 = ("red", "red", "black", "black", " red",   "red" )
```

I want to count how many of a specific item in `ls1` is equal to an item on the same position on `ls2`.

But the counting need to be separated for each item. I don't want the "total" of any matches, but specific for each string. So let's say I want to know how many "red" match. It would give me the answer 2, because the position [0] and [1] of both lists are "red". If I want "black" it would give me 1, since only in the position [3] both match as "black".

I tried to figure out by myself and did a lot of search in this forums but couldn't find an answer for this specific problem. I don't even know where to start. =/

Answer (score 3):

- To iterate a sequence in Python, you use a [for-loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ForLoop).
- To iterate two sequences in parallel,  you use [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip).
- To store the results, use a [dictionary](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries), which maps unique keys to values.
- When you don't know if a key in a dict is present or not, you can supply a default value by using [`dict.get`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get).

Putting all these pieces together:

```
>>> d = {}
>>> for s1, s2 in zip(ls1, ls2):
...     if s1 == s2:
...         d[s1] = d.get(s1, 0) + 1
...         
>>> d
{'red': 2, 'black': 1}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! this is pretty much what i needed =)

Answer (score 3):

As a follow up to [wim's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53232274/1822698), you can also create a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) from a list that only has elements that are equal at the same index:

```
from collections import Counter

ls1 = ("red","red","red", "black","black", "black")
ls2 = ("red", "red", "black", "black", "red", "red")

c = Counter([x for x, y in zip(ls1, ls2) if x == y])
print(c) # Counter({'red': 2, 'black': 1})
```

Comment: This is also very helpful. Thanks!

Comment: Note you don't need to create a list, you can instead feed a generator expression: `Counter(x for x, y in zip(ls1, ls2) if x == y)`.

Answer (score 1):

The general approach is to [iterate through the lists](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_for_loops.asp), and increase the count of matches whenever you find one. Following is a solution in python with comments

```
def getCounts(a, b):
    # Initialize counts
    counts = {}
    # Go through the lists together. Assumption: lists are of same size
    for i in range(len(a)):
        # If elements are equal, increase count
        if a[i] == b[i]:
           counts[a[i]] = counts.get(a[i], 0) + 1
    return counts
```

Answer (score 0):

In case you would like to count all occurrences without specifically items being at the corresponding index, Then this might help

```
res = {}
for i in set(ls2):
    res[i] = ls1.count(i)
print(res)
{'black': 3, 'red': 3}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a 3rd party library, here's a fun way with Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

ls1 = ("red", "red",  "red",  "black", "black", "black")
ls2 = ("red", "red", "black", "black", " red",   "red" )

s1 = pd.Series(ls1)
s2 = pd.Series(ls2)

res = s1.loc[s1 == s2].value_counts().to_dict()

{'black': 1, 'red': 2}
```